# How to make Lightroom recognize geotags in NEF files?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, picasa, geotagging, raw

I usually geotag my pictures with Picasa + Google Earth, while using Lightroom 3.4 for everything else. While this works fine with JPEG pictures, I've discovered that apparently LR doesn't recognize geotags in NEF files (taken with a Nikon D90) tagged this way: if I examine their EXIF metadata in Picasa, geotags are there, but in Lightroom GPS field is missing.

Is there anything I'm missing or a simple workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom 3.x currently does not have native support for geotagging. That would be why you do not even see the field. There are some third-party plugins that can be used to add support for it to Lightroom, though.

[This article](http://www.photohowto.info/adobe-lightroom-3-and-geotagging-step-step-how) may be of some help. The plugin used is [Jeffrey Friedl's GPS Support](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/gps) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom 3 is compatible with geotag information, but it does nothing with it. I add geo info to my RAW files using [GPS Photo Linker](http://www.earlyinnovations.com/gpsphotolinker/),which adds GPS track info from my GPS and automatically adds it to the RAW files. I then import into Lightroom.

Lightroom does not change the location fields, but it also does nothing with them within Lightroom.